# React Required Validation using State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement form validation manually in react for required fields. What i want is to highlight all form without value with red border.

Currently, i was able to make it work to highlight all the form if there's no data present, but whenever i typed anything on the form the data is still highlighted with red. What i really want to do is `highlight the selected input with red border if there isn't any value and prevent the form from submitting.`

Here's my current progress of what i'm doing

`Code for checking if there's a value in the textbox`

```
isProfessionalFormValid(){

    const { firstName, lastName, contactPhone, contactOfficePhone, address, city, companyName, newsletter_subscription} = this.state.formData;

    return firstName && lastName && contactPhone && contactOfficePhone && address && city && companyName && newsletter_subscription;
}


requiredFields(){

    if(!this.isProfessionalFormValid()){
        this.setState({
            errorFirstName: 'error',
            errorLastName: 'error',
            errorAddress: 'error',
            errorCity: 'error',
            errorCompanyName: 'error',
            errorNewsletterSubscription: 'error',
            errorContactPhone: 'error',
            errorContactOfficePhone: 'error',
            errorMessage: ''
        });

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

`Some part of the form being rendered`

```
<form id={"registration_form"} onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)} noValidate>
                <div class="PixelForm-title"> {t('form.registration.title.label')}</div>
                <div className='RegisterModal--line-wrapper'>
                    <div className={'line'} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
                    <input
                        id={"firstName"}
                        placeholder={t('form.registration.first_name.label') + '*'}
                        className={"PixelForm-input" + " " + (this.state.errorFirstName === 'error' ? 'hasError' : '')}
                        type="text"
                        name={"firstName"}
                        required
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.formData.firstName}
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
                    <input
                        id={"lastName"}
                        placeholder={t('form.registration.last_name.label') + '*'}
                        className={"PixelForm-input" + " " + (this.state.errorLastName === 'error' ? 'hasError' : '')}
                        type="text"
                        name={"lastName"}
                        required
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.formData.lastName}
                    />
                </div>

                <PhoneInput name={"contactPhone"}
                            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                            className={"PixelForm-input" + " " + (this.state.errorContactPhone === 'error' ? 'hasError' : '')}
                            placeholder={t('form.registration.mobile_phone.label') + '*'}
                />

                <PhoneInput name={"contactOfficePhone"}
                            onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                            className={"PixelForm-input" + " " + (this.state.errorContactOfficePhone === 'error' ? 'hasError' : '')}
                            placeholder={t('form.registration.office_phone.label')}
                />
                <div className="PixelForm-subheader"> {t('agency_information')}</div>
                <div className='RegisterModal--line-wrapper'>
                    <div className={'line'} />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
                    <input
                        id={"companyName"}
                        placeholder={t('form.registration.broker_name.label') + '*'}
                        className={"PixelForm-input" + " " + (this.state.errorCompanyName === 'error' ? 'hasError' : '')}
                        type="text"
                        name={"companyName"}
                        required
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.formData.companyName}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
                    <input
                        id={"address"}
                        placeholder={t('form.registration.broker_address.label') + '*'}
                        className={"PixelForm-input" + " " + (this.state.errorAddress === 'error' ? 'hasError' : '')}
                        type="text"
                        name={"address"}
                        required
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.formData.address}
                    />
                </div>

                <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
                    <input
                        id={"city"}
                        placeholder={t('form.registration.broker_city.label') + '*'}
                        className={"PixelForm-input" + " " + (this.state.errorCity === 'error' ? 'hasError' : '')}
                        type="text"
                        name={"city"}
                        required
                        onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                        value={this.state.formData.city}
                    />
                </div>

                {(this.state.errorMessage) ? (
                    <div class="PixelForm-error form-group">
                        {t(this.state.errorMessage)}
                    </div>) : ''}


            </form>
```

The output of my current form
[image]

My submit behavior

```
   event.preventDefault();

    if(!this.requiredFields()){
        return false;
    }

    if (!this.checkPhone()) {
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'phone_at_lease_one',
            errorField: 'phone'
        });
        return false;
    }
```

To sum up. I only want to highlight those input without value in red border when submitting the form.

Comment: Any luck on this @kio gipaya?

Comment: still not being able to solve the problem

Comment: @ChristopherNgo do you have any suggestion with my problem? stuck on this for a couple of days now

Comment: I do, I actually just created a sandbox that should give you some insight on how to get this to work. It'll give you a general idea on how to get to this to work, but would have to rework your code a bit. https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-display-input-errors-vfmh5   Let me know if thats similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: this is what i really want to do. i'm just learning with react that's why it give me a hard time fixing some basic issues like this

Comment: Great! I can try modifying your code a bit so it looks a bit more like the sandbox, if that helps. And no worries, in no way would I consider this basic. I'd say you would need at minimum a couple of months working with React to get this to work as expected. If you'd like me to assist, let me know, otherwise, feel free to take it from here.

Comment: Yes if you can modify my code to look like this one you provided please consider it. It will be a very big help for me

Comment: kk. It won't have any of the same styling though, so its really going to be a template. You can fill in the styling later.

Comment: Thank you so much no worries with the styling. I really need to work with the validation behavior

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195452/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-kio-gipaya).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool, so I've modified your component to integrate the form-validation and error-handling as you expected. See the codesandbox here for action: https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-mayer-2ck5z

To note, I commented out the `PhoneInput` component you were using and just used a normal `input` tag as a temporary option. As is, you should be able to swap it seamlessly. Remember to apply your styles. :)

```
import React from "react";

class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputs: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      companyName: "",
      address: "",
      contactPhone: "",
      contactOfficePhone: "",
      city: ""
    },
    errors: {
      firstName: false,
      lastName: false,
      companyName: false,
      address: false,
      contactPhone: false,
      contactOfficePhone: false,
      city: false
    }
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      inputs: {
        ...this.state.inputs,
        [name]: value
      },
      errors: {
        ...this.state.errors,
        [name]: false
      }
    });
  };

  handleOnBlur = event => {
    const { inputs } = this.state;
    if (inputs[event.target.name].length === 0) {
      this.setState(
        {
          errors: {
            ...this.state.errors,
            [event.target.name]: true
          }
        },
        () => console.log(this.state)
      );
    }
  };

  handleOnSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { inputs } = this.state;
    //create new errors object
    let newErrorsObj = Object.entries(inputs)
      .filter(([key, value]) => {
        return value.length === 0;
      })
      .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
        if (value.length === 0) {
          obj[key] = true;
        } else {
          obj[key] = false;
        }
        return obj;
      }, {});

    if (Object.keys(newErrorsObj).length > 0) {
      this.setState(
        {
          errors: newErrorsObj
        },
        () => console.log(this.state)
      );
    } else {
      //submission was succcessful
      //do logic
      console.log("success!");
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <form id="registration_form" onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit} noValidate>
        <div class="PixelForm-title">Register</div>
        <div className="RegisterModal--line-wrapper">
          <div className={"line"} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
          <input
            id={"firstName"}
            placeholder={"first name"}
            className={`PixelForm-input ${errors.firstName ? "hasError" : ""}`}
            type="text"
            name={"firstName"}
            required
            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
            value={this.state.firstName}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
          <input
            id={"lastName"}
            placeholder={"last name"}
            className={`PixelForm-input ${errors.lastName ? "hasError" : ""}`}
            type="text"
            name={"lastName"}
            required
            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
            value={this.state.lastName}
          />
        </div>

        {/*
        going to use a regular input for now, but you can swap this
        */}
        {/* <PhoneInput
          name={"contactPhone"}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          className={
            "PixelForm-input" +
            " " +
            (this.state.errorContactPhone === "error" ? "hasError" : "")
          }
          placeholder={"form.registration.mobile_phone.label" + "*"}
        /> */}

        <input
          name="contactPhone"
          placeholder="contact phone"
          required
          className={`PixelForm-input ${errors.contactPhone ? "hasError" : ""}`}
          onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
          value={this.state.contactPhone}
        />

        {/*<PhoneInput
          name={"contactOfficePhone"}
          onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          className={
            "PixelForm-input" +
            " " +
            (this.state.errorContactOfficePhone === "error" ? "hasError" : "")
          }
          placeholder={t("form.registration.office_phone.label")}
        />*/}
        <input
          name="contactOfficePhone"
          placeholder="contact office phone"
          required
          className={`PixelForm-input ${
            errors.contactOfficePhone ? "hasError" : ""
          }`}
          onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
          value={this.state.contactOfficePhone}
        />

        <div className="PixelForm-subheader"> {"agency_information"}</div>
        <div className="RegisterModal--line-wrapper">
          <div className={"line"} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
          <input
            id={"companyName"}
            placeholder={"company"}
            className={`PixelForm-input ${
              errors.companyName ? "hasError" : ""
            }`}
            type="text"
            name={"companyName"}
            required
            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
            value={this.state.companyName}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
          <input
            id={"address"}
            placeholder={"address"}
            className={`PixelForm-input ${errors.address ? "hasError" : ""}`}
            type="text"
            name={"address"}
            required
            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
            value={this.state.address}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group PixelFormField">
          <input
            id={"city"}
            placeholder={"city"}
            className={`PixelForm-input ${errors.city ? "hasError" : ""}`}
            type="text"
            name={"city"}
            required
            onChange={e => this.handleOnChange(e)}
            value={this.state.city}
          />
        </div>

        {Object.values(errors).includes(true) ? (
          <div class="PixelForm-error form-group">
            You forgot to fill something out
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to run your logic for check the status of your input fields when the user click the SUBMIT button instead of when a user is typing in each single field.

You can prevent form submission by using `e.preventDefault()` ([More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)).

To do that you could use:

```
<form onSubmit={this.requiredFields}>
```

---

```
requiredFields(e){
    if(!this.isProfessionalFormValid()){
        e.preventDefault(); // << Prevent form submission
        this.setState({
            errorFirstName: 'error',
            errorLastName: 'error',
            errorAddress: 'error',
            errorCity: 'error',
            errorCompanyName: 'error',
            errorNewsletterSubscription: 'error',
            errorContactPhone: 'error',
            errorContactOfficePhone: 'error',
            errorMessage: ''
        });

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing this on my submit form i usually check if by `if(!requiredForm){ return false; }

Comment: instead of return false please try use `e.preventDefault()` as shown in my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. All fields have to non-empty then only it will work.

```
    getFieldsThatHasError() {
      return this.state.formData.reduce((soFar, value, key) => {
        if (!value) {
          soFar[key] = 'error'
        }

        return soFar
      }, {})
    }

    requiredFields() {
      const errorFields = getFieldsThatHasError()

      this.setState({
        ...errorFields,
        errorMessage: ''
      })

      if (Object.keys(errorFields).length) {
        return false
      }

      return true
    }
```

Comment: I will check on this one

Comment: I'm also having issue that formData.reduce is not a function

Comment: @kiogipaya formData initially is an object right?? because reduce is only work with object type and what is the error you are having with errorFields??